# angular2-meteor with PrimeNG

Tags: angular, meteor, primeng

I am working on a project with Angular-Meteor and it is working great. As my starting point I made use of https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor-base. Now I would like to install PrimeNG as my UI. The documentation on http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup says I need a module manager like webpack or system.js to bind the dependencies. None of them exists on the angular-meteor-base project. I don't even understand how that works, because even on the Angular2 page, the boilerplate example contains a module loader. How does the module management works on Angular-Meteor base example, and how can I add PrimeNG.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Meteor already includes its own package / plugin / module manager (do not confuse them with Angular "modules").

In particular, it works well with `npm` now, so a simple `import {myModule} from "primeng/primeng";` statement should work. Of course, make sure you have installed `primeng` through `npm` (command `npm install primeng --save`), as mentioned in the setup page you link to.

Meteor will then automatically include the required scripts into your app bundle.

Then you are left with including the appropriate CSS and related images / fonts. I think webpack automatically handles the links within CSS to images and fonts (do not know for SystemJS), but it is not the case with Meteor.

A simple workaround is to copy them into your `public` folder, with the appropriate subfolder(s) structure (like `public/images/` or `public/fonts/`, depending on how these assets are placed relatively with the original CSS files).

As for the CSS files themselves, just include them anywhere in your `client` folder, and Meteor will bundle them.